# Are these statements always true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, soft-question, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I haven't found an answer in my books. Although the question seems very simple, I want to ask.

Are these statements always  true?

> a) For any infinity non-negative integer sequence, if there is an exist $n-$th term closed form expression formula, for this sequence, we have always a recurrence formula.
>
> b) For any infinity non-negative integer sequence, if there is an exist recurrence formula,for this sequence, we have always $n-$th term closed form expression formula.
>
> c) For any infinity non-negative integer sequence, if there is not an exist recurrence formula,for this sequence, we don't have an any $n-$th term closed form expression formula.

Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way c) is logically equivalent to a) (that is, if a) is true, c) will be true, and if a) is false, c) will be false). This is because c) is just the [contrapositive](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50844/confusion-about-an-implications-contrapositive) of a) (assuming I interpreted things correctly). So you don't really need to ask c) separately.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth If you want You can answer the question in more detail. :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Closed form expression" is rather ambiguous, but...

(a), (c): trivially yes, because $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is a difference of two closed form expressions.

(b): like in the analogous case of calculation of primitives, we can have a recurrence expression without closed form solution.

Quote from [$A = B$](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/wilf/AeqBAllFonts.pdf):

> The following sequences cannot be expressed in closed form. That is
>   to say, in each case the sequence cannot be exhibited as a sum of a fixed (independent of $n$) number of hypergeometric terms:
>
> $\bullet$ The sum of the cubes of the binomial coefficients of order $n$, i.e. $\sum\binom{n}k^3$
>
> $\bullet$ The number of derangements (fixed-point free permutations) of $n$ letters.
>
> $\bullet$ The central trinomial coefficient, i.e., the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1 + x + x^2)^n$.
>
> $\dots$